# MediaStreamTrack.captureFrame is capturing the image from video which is colorless

Tags: flutter, webrtc

I want to take a picture of the video stream. I am using the method MediaStreamTrack.captureFrame to take the picture. However, the image taken ends up to be a colorless image.

Below is the sample image.
[image]

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure out what's causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Hi, I haven't figure out the way to fix it